# Injecting Service using Angular Seed - 'Unknown provider' error

Tags: angularjs

I'm following a PluralSight tutorial on AngularJS fundamentals. Though I'm using a much different structure as I seem to have a much newer version of Angular Seed.

I'm trying to inject a service into controller using the same syntax structure as I have done before, which was working fine, but this one brings the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eventDataProvider <- eventData
```

### viewEventDetails.js (Controller)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.viewEventDetails', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/viewEventDetails', {
        templateUrl: 'viewEventDetails/viewEventDetails.html',
        controller: 'viewEventDetailsCtrl'
    });
}])
.controller('viewEventDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', 'eventData', function($scope, eventData) {
    $scope.sortorder = '-upVoteCount';
    $scope.event = eventData.getEvent(function (event) {
       $scope.event = event;
    });

    $scope.upVoteSession = function (session) {
        session.upVoteCount++;
    };
    $scope.downVoteSession = function (session) {
        session.upVoteCount--;
    };
}
]);
```

### EventData.js (Service)

```
angular.module('myApp.services', [])
.factory('eventData', ['$http', '$log', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
        getEvent: function () {
            $http({ method: 'get', url: '/data/event/1' })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.warn(data, status, headers(), config);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.warn(data, status, headers(), config);
                });
        }
    }
}]
);
```

### app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'myApp.filters',
'myApp.services',
'myApp.viewNewEvent',
'myApp.viewEventDetails',
'myApp.viewEditProfile',
'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to inject the `myApp.services` into your module that the controller is in, since the modules are different.

i.e.

```
angular.module('myApp.viewEventDetails', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.services'])
```

Comment: I've done this which did not fix it, but I then tried giving the service a different name and then injecting it like this and it works. Does this mean all modules need a unique name, and cant share names through files?

Comment: hmm, ok I think what I hear you saying is that you have more than one javascript file representing a service that uses `angular.module('myApp.services', [])`.  this is definitely a problem, as each module can only be instantiated once.  you can, however, assign the module to a variable, i.e. `var services = angular.module('myApp.services', [])`, and then reference the `services` variable in multiple files, like `services.factory(` though this breaks a bit of the SoC.